# Codename one: Make swipeable container swipe only to the left

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

I just added swipeable container to my app and it is working perfectly, only thing is I want it to only to swipe to the left, from what I read in the documentary is, that I can either make it swipe to the right with

```
public SwipeableContainer(Component bottomLeft,
                          Component top)
```

or make it swipe right and left

```
public SwipeableContainer(Component bottomLeft,
                          Component bottomRight,
                          Component top)
```

Since iOS swipe is normally always to the left for deleting a list item, I want it that way too to create a good feeling for the user. Anyone knows how to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized that by simply

```
public SwipeableContainer(null,
                          Component bottomRight,
                          Component top)
```

I can achieve it.